# Device to help find my buried well

Tags: well, locating

So, I am in need of something that will help me find my buried well cap.

Basically I want to attach something small to the end of a steel line and then track with the phone through the ground.

I've seen a number of things which seem close but my knowledge and experience is such that I need more help in focusing my efforts.

Comment: Please explain (in your question) why you think a steel line and a phone make useful components in a well finding expedition. You might also explain what the well cap is made of, it's size and depth. It should be obvious that this is required information.

Comment: I've just noticed that you've tagged the question with 'bluetooth' and 'rfid'. How will Bluetooth or RFID help unless there is a Bluetooth or [RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) device in your well cap. Is there?

Comment: I think maybe he has a pipe leading to the well cap, and he plans to push an RFID tag or similar down the pipe on a steel wire, and follow that above ground with the phone? Either way, the question needs to be clearer.

Comment: If this is a product recommendation rather than design question, it is off topic.

Comment: @user2943160: He's obviously looking for a technique.

Comment: Non-tech solution: go to your office of public records and try to find the work permit for when the well was put in. From there, see if there are drawings/plans with the permit or contact the contractor who put the well in, if they still exist.

Comment: There are devices that will track a buried steel line with a RF signal applied to it - but they are not a phone. Look for documents, which will typically have a distance from two points such as foundation corners (draw an arc from each, X marks the spot), hire a line locator service with the right tools, or dig outside your house where the waterline comes out, and figure it goes in a straight line most of the time for digging the next hole. When you find the well, have the casing extended above ground (buried caps are so last-century.)

Comment: I agree with extending the cap above ground, my neighbors got very sick because of fecal contamination from surface water getting into the well. Line tracers can be rented and will be able to locate the pipe.+